How to add a collection element in appsettings.production.json without overwriting the collection from appsettings.json
I want to add a collection element to application configuration for certain environments like production or development, without overwriting already present collection elements added earlier through appsettings.json.
If I have an appsettings.json like this:
{
    "mySettings" : {
        "myKey": "myValue
    }
}

I can add to mySettings in appsettings.production.json
{
    "mySettings" : {
        "myOtherKey": "myValue
    }
}

and both values myKey and myOtherKey will be present in the resulting configuration.
But how to add to a collection element without overwriting the existing collection? If my appsettings.json is
{
    "mySettings" : {
        "providers": [
            {
                "name": "myFirstProvider"
            }
        ]
    }
}

and my appsettings.production.json adds another provider key like this:
{
    "mySettings" : {
        "providers": [
            {
                "name": "myAdditionalProductionProvider"
            }
        ]
    }
}

then the element for myFirstProvider will be overwritten.
Is there a syntax where I can add to collection elements in a later configuration sources without overwriting the existing collection from earlier configuration sources? I am on Net 8.
